# Unterminated statement works in Java

Tags: java, netbeans, while-loop

For a CS class I had to print all of the powers of 2 less than `n`. I wrote the following code, where I purposefully omitted the semicolon at the end of the statement inside the loop.
Why does this work? In C++ you'd get a nasty error. Can you provide a technical explanation of what the compiler tried to do?

```
int n = 100;

int a = 0;
while (Math.pow(2, a++) < n) {
    System.out.println(Math.pow(2, a))
}
```

The IDE that this happens in is NetBeans.

NetBeans shows that it can't compile (it goes red), but it runs anyway. Can someone explain, using the JVM perhaps, why this happens?

Comment: That's *not* valid standard Java. Either you've got a bizarre compiler, or that's not the code that you're compiling. When I try to compile that exact code, I get: `Test.java:11: error: ';' expected`

Comment: @JonSkeet I ran this just fine using NetBeans. I had to tell it to "Run Anyway". Is NetBeans a bizarre compiler? You guys sure do downvote quickly before you investigate.

Comment: @John It not possible

Comment: @JonSkeet I know that. That's exactly why I'm asking.

Comment: May be netbean internally maintain it.But you cant compile using cmd

Comment: @Niks Okay. NetBeans shows that it can't _compile_ (it goes red), but it runs anyway. Can someone explain, using the JVM perhaps, why this happens?

Comment: At some point you probably checked the option to 'always run anyway' when Netbeans gives you a warning about uncompilable stuff. You should probably find out where to uncheck that. Normally you have to click through a dialog to run this but Netbeans does compile and run it.

Comment: @SimonKuang: You didn't think to mention that it didn't compile? Your question gives the distinct impression that it runs without error - "works" isn't the same as "complains but runs anyway"

Comment: This is really strange. NetBeans says that it "compiled with errors," but you can run it anyway. This is fresh code, there's no "cached" or previous version that it could have fallen back on.

Comment: @John: "I had to tell it to Run Anyway" isn't the same as "ran just fine" in my view. The question missed out crucial information, IMO.

Comment: The question and comments by OP are served incorrectly

Comment: @SimonKuang: This is basically a matter of some Java compilers (but far from all) allowing you to run even if not *all* of it compiled. Eclipse does the same thing to possibly a different extent - if a method couldn't be compiled, the bytecode generated will throw an UnresolvedCompilationError as soon as you invoke it.

Comment: @JonSkeet Thank you for sharing your view of what "ran just fine" means. It was extremely educational. Now let me share my view: "ran just fine", to me, means that no errors occurred while it ran. Now we have both shared our opinions on what "ran just fine" means!

Comment: @John: You had to tell it to "run anyway" - the IDE objected. (The IDE that you happened to use, which happened to be the one that the OP used, although that wasn't specified in the question...) Think of it another way: if a colleague checked in this code, and when you objected they said: "It ran just fine on my machine" how would you feel?

Comment: @JonSkeet It **didn't** "compile just fine," in fact, it compiled with errors. It **did** *run* just fine, because the compilation (with errors) still managed to produce the correct bytecode. Compilation and running are different things.

Comment: @trutheality: I would suggest that complaining before running isn't the same as "running just fine". If you have to go through what is effectively a warning dialog before doing something where normally you wouldn't, it's not "just fine". Anyway, my main point is that the question doesn't mention *any* of that, nor even which IDE is involved. It's a poor question, and I'm perfectly content with my downvote.

Comment: @JonSkeet And I would suggest that this question reveals an interesting quirk (feature?) in the behavior of NetBeans, which makes it a good question, particularly considering that it yielded Radiodef's excellent answer and the much less valid code example that NetBeans nevertheless manages to compile. Also I edited the OP's comments into the question fixing the issue with the details not mentioned. Remember: what makes a question good isn't the person asking, but the answers and insight it yields.

Comment: @trutheality: With your edits, it's fine. But in its original form, it was not. And I disagree with your idea that the goodness of a question is determined by the usefulness of its answers. A good question can have awful answers, and vice versa. Hence the Reversal badge. The OP should take note of the flaws in his original question, and nit repeat them.

Comment: @JonSkeet If I stabbed you and then ate a delicious cookie, would you then claim that my cookie was not delicious?

Comment: @John: Nope, but if getting to the delicious part involved getting through a stale egg covering, I wouldn't claim that "eating the cookie was a delicious experience". I view the act of starting the app as part of running it - and when that gives a warning then I don't consider it to be "running just fine".

Comment: @JonSkeet Please educate us on the proper term for *"the series of events that occur between the first instruction of a program and the last instruction"*. Furthermore, you took my phrase out of context with your colleague example. I prefaced it with *"after I clicked Run Anyway"*. Your practice of correcting phrases written by other fluent English speakers is annoying at best. My comment was helpful because it was the first to point out that the code will actually run successfully in <x> environment after taking <y> actions. Your response to my comment was simply not relevant to the question.

Comment: @John: This is clearly going nowhere. We'll have to agree to disagree on the niceties of whether "ran just fine" is appropriate. But I find it hard to see how you can disagree with my assertion that the original question was poor: 1) It didn't provide enough contextual information (the IDE involved); 2) It didn't provide enough information about what the OP knew and didn't know (see the OP's reaction to my comment); 3) It didn't provide nearly enough diagnostic information about what actually happened. Given those, I think a downvote was entirely reasonable, contrary to your first comment.

Comment: @JonSkeet It wasn't until people started commenting that the OP even knew that the odd behavior had anything to do with his IDE. I would point out that your first comment claimed that he had a bizarre compiler, when he was in fact using NetBeans.

Comment: @John: The OP knew more than the question said, because he knew the code didn't successfully compile. Given that he was talking about unexpected compiler behaviour, it would have been very sensible to mention which compiler was being used. (If it were me, I'd have tried a different compiler as well, and reported on the differences.) The original post gave the definite impression that all was fine - that it was running just as any valid code would. The OP *knew* that wasn't the case, but left that out of the question. Still a bad question IMO, and I hope the OP learns to ask better ones.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/48619/discussion-between-jon-skeet-and-john)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

In Netbeans you should have to click through the following dialog to run this...

[image: Run Anyway]

If you do, it runs without an error and this is probably just due to their parser/lexer generating the same bytecode regardless of the missing semicolon.

Netbeans will compile and run it this way too:

```
int n = 100

int a = 0
while Math.pow(2, a++) < n
    System.out.println(Math.pow(2, a
```

So, again, it's probably just that their parser/lexer generates the same output. All a parser and lexer will do is take the source code, turn it in to a series of recognized tokens and turn those in to an instruction set. It would be possible to feed a parser/lexer complete gibberish and receive runnable output sometimes. Here, it seems the Netbeans parsing and lexing routines do not need delimiters to determine where certain expressions end.

**This does not in any way mean that the runnable output is the same as the input as interpreted by a person**. It just means the sequence of generated instructions happened to be valid. That is what the dialog box is warning us about. Clicking 'Run Anyway' means "I don't care what happens".

If you don't get that dialog box it's probably because at some point you checked 'Always run without asking' and you should probably find where the option is to enable it again since it's useful. Sometimes you can get a compilation error in a file you aren't looking at and this dialog will notify you of that.

Answer (score 3):

NetBeans is somewhat strange. If you try to run something with compiler errors, and you say to "run anyway", NetBeans will do what it can to make the code make sense. If the error is `';' expected`, NetBeans will add a semicolon. For a `not a statement` error, it will replace the line with this:

```
throw new RuntimeException("not a statement");
```

NetBeans will do similar things for other errors.

Comment: Where are you getting this "replacing" behavior from? I didn't see that happening when I tried it.

Comment: Oh, it's not replacing. It's adding the semicolon, then adding this line after the new line.

Comment: This must be some custom behavior in your settings. Mine isn't doing any of that.

Comment: what is it doing? when I tried it a while back, that's what it did.

Comment: I was using netbeans 7.1 back then

Comment: It doesn't change the source at all, it just says that it "compiled with errors." It still produces a `.class` file with working bytecode. This is NetBeans 7.1.1.

Comment: well, i'm stumped. I don't have netbeans in front of me right now, so I can't try.

Comment: what I mean by it changing the source is when i decompiled it, I got different code.

Comment: Netbeans does indeed do this sometimes, though not for the OP's specific code. Netbeans will do this for `1;` for example.